# NSSearchField with Suggestions view underneath like Spotlight MacOS cocoa Swift 4.2

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode10, swift4.2, nssearchfield

I want to write a MacOS Cocoa Desktop App with XCode 10 and Swift 4.2.
It should have a searchfield with a suggestions view opening as you keep typing like Google Search or Spotlight with autocompletion.
However I'm completely new to Cocoa programming.

I have already tried to add an NSSearchField and a dynamically added NSPopOver object with subclass of NSTableView which contains all the suggestions. But I am not happy with the suggestions view because of the anchor/arrow that appears with it. It seems like it breaks the UI guidelines.

Thus I have tried to implement my own custom subclass of NSView containing the suggestions. It works fine but I struggle with simple things like making it hide/disappear as soon as any other area is clicked in the app.

Does anyone know a good example as best practice for this task or have some sample code?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you Ken. I had a look at this  already but this sample is from 2012 and seems to be outdated and it is written in Objective C. Do you maybe know anything else?

Comment: Just because it's from 2012 doesn't mean it's not still applicable. Sorry, I'm not aware of another sample for a similar purpose.

Comment: Take a look at [SearchField Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SearchField/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) (from 2015).